# Group data and display averages in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, grouping, average

I have a Excel dataset that includes data on program observations, which usually consist of more than one observation per visit (varying number of rows per visit). Each row includes the site name, the date, and the ratings on items that make up three domains.

I need to find the means for each of those three domains grouped by the site/date. For example, Site A visited on 6/1/2020 has 3 observations, and each observation has ratings for each of the items. These items across the 3 observations need to be averaged into domains 1, 2, and 3. For the purpose of this example, A-F is domain 1, G-K is domain 2, and L-P is domain 3.

The first image below shows an example of what it would look like to start, and the second image shows what I would like it to look like.

I have coded the formulas for the averages for each domain across all observations (code included below, which is from actual data rather than example), but I'm not sure how to get VBA to do this in a loop for each different combination of site and date and spit it out into a new worksheet. Please let me know if this is unclear! I'm new to VBA.
**Original Data**

[image: image1]

**Desired Result**

[image: image2]

```
ws2.Range("D1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws1.Range("Y6:Y" & lastrow & ",Z6:Z" & lastrow & ",AA6:AA" & lastrow _
    & ",AD6:AD" & lastrow & ",AE6:AE" & lastrow & ",AI6:AI" & lastrow & ",AK6:AK" & lastrow & ",AL6:AL" & lastrow))

    ws2.Range("E1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws1.Range("AF6:AF" & lastrow & ",AM6:AM" & lastrow & ",AP6:AP" & lastrow _
    & ",AQ6:AQ" & lastrow & ",AR6:AR" & lastrow & ",AS6:AS" & lastrow & ",AT6:AT" & lastrow & ",AU6:AU" & lastrow))

    ws2.Range("F1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws1.Range("AW6:AW" & lastrow & ",AX6:AX" & lastrow & ",AY6:AY" & lastrow))
```

Comment: How does your program know that `a-f` = `Domain 1`, etc?  Is there some algorithm?  Or do you just hard code it?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld sorry if that was unclear -- that's what I calculated in my code above. I have the first domain calculated in D1, the second in E1, and the third in F1. The pasted code is just from my actual data rather than the example data I posted here.

Comment: So the `Domains` are arbitrary and will **always** be tied to those same columns?  Also, if you have the same site with observations on different dates, how do you want to see that in the output?

Comment: Yes, they'll always be tied to the same columns. The same site with more than one observation date should be a new row. Using the example above, there might be a row for site A on 6/1/2020, a row for site B on 6/2/2020, a row for site A on 10/15/2020, and a row for site B on 10/17/2020.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem differently.

It uses a lot of time to have multiple worksheet accesses from VBA. It is generally much faster to work in VBA. One can read the range into an array in a single step; process in VBA, and then write it back and format in a single step.

Routines often operate 5-10x more quickly this way.

So

- Declare worksheets for the data source and results
- Read the data into a VBA array
- Process the data, organizing it into a Dictionary object

  - Use a Class (User Defined Object) to collect data for each `Site/Date` combination, including a collection of the ratings for each Domain.
  - The function that assigns domain names depending on the contents of the first row is there for flexibility, in case something changes in the future.
- Organize the output into a results array
- Write the results array back to the worksheet and format it.

***Be sure to read the notes in the code***

#### Class Module (*rename this cSite*)

```
'Set Reference (on the Tools/References dropdown) to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'Rename cSite
Option Explicit

Private pSite As String
Private pDt As Date
Private pDomainValue As Long
Private pDomainName As String
Private pDomains As Dictionary

Public Property Get Site() As String
    Site = pSite
End Property
Public Property Let Site(Value As String)
    pSite = Value
End Property


Public Property Get Dt() As Date
    Dt = pDt
End Property
Public Property Let Dt(Value As Date)
    pDt = Value
End Property

Public Property Get DomainValue() As Long
    DomainValue = pDomainValue
End Property
Public Property Let DomainValue(Value As Long)
    pDomainValue = Value
End Property

Public Property Get DomainName() As String
    DomainName = pDomainName
End Property
Public Property Let DomainName(Value As String)
    pDomainName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Domains() As Dictionary
    Set Domains = pDomains
End Property
Public Function addDomainsItem(domName, domValue)
    Dim v
    If pDomains.Exists(domName) Then
        v = pDomains(domName)
        ReDim Preserve v(UBound(v) + 1)
        v(UBound(v)) = domValue
        pDomains(domName) = v
    Else
        ReDim v(0)
        v(0) = domValue
        pDomains.Add domName, v
    End If
End Function

Public Function avgDomain(domName) As Double
    Dim Num As Double, deNom As Long
    Dim v
    For Each v In Me.Domains(domName)
        Num = Num + v
        deNom = deNom + 1
    Next v
    avgDomain = Num / deNom
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pDomains = New Dictionary
        pDomains.CompareMode = TextCompare
End Sub
```

#### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
Sub sites()
    Dim dS As Dictionary, cS As cSite
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, sKey As String
    Dim v, w
    
'set up the data source and results worksheets, source array, result range
Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11")

On Error Resume Next
    Set wsRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9
            Worksheets.Add after:=wsSrc
            ActiveSheet.Name = "Results"
            Set wsRes = Worksheets("Results")
        Case Is <> 0
            MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
            Exit Sub
    End Select
On Error GoTo 0

Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)
With wsSrc
    'last row
    I = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'last column
    J = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(I, J))
End With

'read and organize the data into a dictionary
Set dS = New Dictionary

For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    sKey = vSrc(I, 1) & "|" & vSrc(I, 2)
    Set cS = New cSite
    With cS
        If Not dS.Exists(sKey) Then
            .Site = vSrc(I, 1)
            .Dt = vSrc(I, 2)
            For J = 3 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
                .DomainName = myDomain(CStr(vSrc(1, J)))
                .DomainValue = vSrc(I, J)
                .addDomainsItem .DomainName, .DomainValue
            Next J
            dS.Add KEY:=sKey, Item:=cS
        Else
            With dS(sKey)
                For J = 3 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
                    .DomainName = myDomain(CStr(vSrc(1, J)))
                    .DomainValue = vSrc(I, J)
                    .addDomainsItem .DomainName, .DomainValue
                Next J
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next I

For Each v In dS.Keys
    For Each w In dS(v).Domains
        Debug.Print v, w, dS(v).avgDomain(w)
    Next w
Next v

'create output array
ReDim vRes(0 To dS.Count, 1 To 5)

'Header Rows
vRes(0, 1) = "Site"
vRes(0, 2) = "Date"
vRes(0, 3) = myDomain("a")
vRes(0, 4) = myDomain("g")
vRes(0, 5) = myDomain("l")

'Data
I = 0
For Each v In dS.Keys
    I = I + 1
    With dS(v)
        vRes(I, 1) = .Site
        vRes(I, 2) = .Dt
        J = 2
        For Each w In .Domains
            J = J + 1
            vRes(I, J) = .avgDomain(w)
        Next w
    End With
Next v

'write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Columns(2).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    With .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count))
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End With
    .Style = "Output" 'might need to change this if not English language
    .Rows(1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
    
End Sub

Function myDomain(S As String) As String
    Select Case S
        Case "a" To "f"
            myDomain = "Domain 1"
        Case "g" To "k"
            myDomain = "Domain 2"
        Case "l" To "r"
            myDomain = "Domain 3"
    End Select
End Function
```

**Original Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]